# Which "statistic" is proper for "StatusCheckFailed" metric while setting CloudWatch alarms?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I'm setting many alarms for our team's EC2 instance.

While setting an alarm for `StatusCheckFailed` metric, which is returning `1` or `0`, whether `1` corresponds system's or instance's failing status and `0` when everything is good.

My question is about which "statistic" is proper for binary values like this.

*Below is an image to give some context

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `Maximum` or `Sum`. Set the alarm to activate when the stats is greater than 0.